# how to check string value and refresh the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker, global-asax

i have a static string in static class, its getting value from desktop application,

on asp.net i have to check that its null or have value, if it has value , i want to

show it on label (on aspx page) , i have put a backgroud worker in global.asax,

```
public static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public static int ID = 0;
      //  public static List&lt;Person&gt; personList = new List&lt;Person&gt;();
        public static string personList;
        public static bool stopWorker = false;
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
            // Calling the DoWork Method Asynchronously
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();



    private static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //foreach (Person p in personList)
        //{
        personList = Class1.GetDataFromDesktop;
        //}
    }
```

its checking value time to time, but i am unable to show the response on label which is on aspx page
, what to do, is there any other process or i can do it using global.asax

Comment: just to be sure to understand you: your desktop application is running on your webserver?

Comment: i include desktop app in web browser app using windows host control,
now runng xbap in a frame to run the desktop app

Comment: i have started to do it through java script , i am checking the data within the static string member, which is changing, but not getting shown on asp.net page, b/c that string member is on server side, page have to have  refresh to get new value of string..how can i get value of static string member through java script function,any suggestion,?  or i use global.asax to get dynamic value?

Comment: i am getting value in javascript thorugh this, but its not getting changed..

var myVar;
   myVar=  <% ="\""+Class1.GetDataFromDesktop + "\"" %> ;
  document.getElementById("TextBox2").value=myVar;
     setInterval(function () { myFunction(); }, 10000);